# Lua - Removing words that are not in a list

Tags: string, lua

i want to remove words that are not in a list, from a string.

for example i have the string "**i like pie and cake**" or "**pie and cake is good**" and i want to remove words that are not "**pie**" or "**cake**" and end out with a string saying "**pie cake**".

it would be great, if the words it does not delete could be loaded from a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another solution, but you may need to trim the last space in the result.

```
acceptable = { "pie", "cake" }
for k,v in ipairs(acceptable) do acceptable[v]=v.." " end
setmetatable(acceptable,{__index= function () return "" end})

function strip(s,t)
    s=s.." "
    print('"'..s:gsub("(%a+) %s*",t)..'"')
end

strip("i like pie and cake",acceptable)
strip("pie and cake is good",acceptable)
```

`gsub` is the key point here. There are other variations using `gsub` and a function, instead of setting a metatable for `acceptable`.

Comment: Nice one, actually,  although I would prefer to wrap it all in a function without a metatable.

Answer (score 3):

```
local function stripwords(inputstring, inputtable)
  local retstring = {}
  local itemno = 1;
  for w in string.gmatch(inputstring, "%a+") do
     if inputtable[w] then
       retstring[itemno] = w
       itemno = itemno + 1
     end
  end

  return table.concat(retstring, " ")
end
```

Provided that the words you want to keep are all keys of the `inputtable`.

Comment: Instead of concatenating the string in the loop, you could just send in a space as a second parameter: `table.concat(retstring, " ")`

Comment: You can avoid testing for `itemno > 1` by setting `del=""` before the loop and setting `del=" "` in the loop, at the end.

Comment: @lhf, yup, that would do as well, but Netfangled's proposal is better, I think

Answer (score 0):

The following also implements the last part of the request (I hope):

> it would be great, if the words it does not delete could be loaded from a table.

```
function stripwords(str, words)
    local w = {};
    return str:gsub("([^%s.,!?]+)%s*", function(word)
        if words[word] then return "" end
        w[#w+1] = word
    end), w;
end
```

Keep in mind that the pattern matcher of Lua is not compatible with multibyte strings. This is why I used the pattern above. If you don't care about multibyte strings, you can use something like `"(%a+)%s"`. In that case I would also run the words through `string.upper`

### Tests / Usage

```
local blacklist = { some = true, are = true, less = true, politics = true }
print((stripwords("There are some nasty words in here!", blacklist)))

local r, t = stripwords("some more are in politics here!", blacklist);
print(r);
for k,v in pairs(t) do
    print(k, v);
end
```